# Doctrine query language ORDER BY using a field in a foreign entity

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I have 3 entites:

1. User
2. Session
3. SessionInProgress

and some associations:

1. Bidirectional Many `User` to Many `SessionInProgress` (`SessionInProgress` has a `$users` array which stores the users involved in a session - mentor and student. A `User` entity also refers back to its sessions in progress through an array `$sessions`)
2. Bidirectional One `Session` To Many `SessionInProgress` (A given session may have many sessions in progress, and a session in progress refers back to its corresponding `Session` using `$session`)

I want to fetch the sessions that are in progress for a given user, ordered by a field called `$num` in `Session` using DQL, so I think I need a DQL like:

```
SELECT s FROM SessionInProgress sip JOIN sip.session s WHERE :givenUser MEMBER OF sip.users ORDER BY s.num ASC
```

and so I wrote:

```
public function findAllOrderedByNum($user)
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    return $qb
            ->select('s')
            ->from('SessionInProgress', 'sip')
            ->join('sip.session', 's')
            ->where($qb->expr()->in('?1', 'sip.users'))
            ->orderBy('s.num', 'ASC')
            ->setParameter(1, $user)
            ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
}
```

Is this correct? I'm not very familiar with DQL or the `QueryBuilder` syntax

Comment: And what is the problem? Are you getting wrong data? Are you getting errors?

Comment: No I'm asking whether this will work. I haven't finished all my controller logic so I can't really execute this DQL anywhere right now

Comment: Looks fine to me , any error?